# Apple Id Reactivation

Tags: mail.app

I am trying to re-activate my Apple ID which I have not used for about 1 year. The issue is to be able to re-activate my Apple ID (after being de-activated), I need to answer my security questions or  enter my old mobile phone number. The only issue is I have forgotten them.

How would I go about re-activating my Apple ID again?

Comment: You'll have to contact Apple then

Answer (score 2):

The only way then is to call the Apple-support which can be found here: http://www.apple.com/support/contact/

Please be aware of possible extra phone fees.